# Error while installing librosa with pip: Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully

Tags: librosa

(faridi) humayanfaridi@Faridi PYTHON % pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
Using cached scipy-1.11.3.tar.gz (56.3 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [44 lines of output]
+ meson setup /private/var/folders/rr/5g7gjfn91q39dxfg_1cmhl200000gp/T/pip-install-n2cz87mk/scipy_23fb51e6009a47b59ccdcf0b3cbd47d8 /private/var/folders/rr/5g7gjfn91q39dxfg_1cmhl200000gp/T/pip-install-n2cz87mk/scipy_23fb51e6009a47b59ccdcf0b3cbd47d8/.mesonpy-gxbsgp11 -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=/private/var/folders/rr/5g7gjfn91q39dxfg_1cmhl200000gp/T/pip-install-n2cz87mk/scipy_23fb51e6009a47b59ccdcf0b3cbd47d8/.mesonpy-gxbsgp11/meson-python-native-file.ini
The Meson build system
Version: 1.2.3
Source dir: /private/var/folders/rr/5g7gjfn91q39dxfg_1cmhl200000gp/T/pip-install-n2cz87mk/scipy_23fb51e6009a47b59ccdcf0b3cbd47d8
Build dir: /private/var/folders/rr/5g7gjfn91q39dxfg_1cmhl200000gp/T/pip-install-n2cz87mk/scipy_23fb51e6009a47b59ccdcf0b3cbd47d8/.mesonpy-gxbsgp11
Build type: native build
Project name: SciPy
Project version: 1.11.3
C compiler for the host machine: cc (clang 13.0.0 "Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)")
C linker for the host machine: cc ld64 711
C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (clang 13.0.0 "Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)")
C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld64 711
Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 0.29.36)
Host machine cpu family: aarch64
Host machine cpu: aarch64
Program python found: YES (/Users/humayanfaridi/PYTHON/faridi/bin/python3.12)
Did not find pkg-config by name 'pkg-config'
Found Pkg-config: NO
Run-time dependency python found: YES 3.12
Program cython found: YES (/private/var/folders/rr/5g7gjfn91q39dxfg_1cmhl200000gp/T/pip-build-env-ar24gy4s/overlay/bin/cython)
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: YES
Library m found: YES

```
  ../meson.build:82:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['nvfortran'], ['pgfortran'], ['ifort'], ['ifx'], ['g95']]
  The following exception(s) were encountered:
  Running `gfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
  Running `gfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
  Running `flang --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
  Running `flang -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
  Running `nvfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
  Running `nvfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
  Running `pgfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
  Running `pgfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
  Running `ifort --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
  Running `ifort -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
  Running `ifx --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifx'"
  Running `ifx -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifx'"
  Running `g95 --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
  Running `g95 -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
  
  A full log can be found at /private/var/folders/rr/5g7gjfn91q39dxfg_1cmhl200000gp/T/pip-install-n2cz87mk/scipy_23fb51e6009a47b59ccdcf0b3cbd47d8/.mesonpy-gxbsgp11/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I still can install other packages like lpytq5 but can't install librosa. I'm installing everything in virtual environment.